# making user profile available for anonymous user viewing

Tags: nodes, users

I am creating a views to list the users in that I want anyone to be able to access the user's profile node. However,there doesnt seem to have any such options. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same problem and was able to solve it by going to EDIT VIEW > ACCESS (under Page Settings) > PERMISSION and changing it to VIEW COMMENTS. Then in the POEPLE > PERMISSIONS area I made sure that anonymous users were permitted to view comments.